# Adding a list of values to a column in sqlite table

Tags: python, list, sqlite

so i am able to create a new table in my database and harvest all the information from a file to fill all but the last column in the table using cursor, and execute as one would normally do.

the last column of information comes from a different source and is in my code as a list of integers.  how would i go about adding this list of integers into my last column?

i've tried various loops and iterations, but i am just missing something (probably quite obvious) in how to phrase it properly.

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
for j in list:
    cursor.execute('insert into Table (column) values (?)', j)
connection.commit()
```

and i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Homework/Homework7/bam_counting.py", line 157, in <module>
    cursor.execute('insert into Genes (counts) values (?)', j)
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `INSERT INTO...` then sqlite will create a new row.
You must use `UPDATE table ...` to update rows that already exist.

You will need to tell sqlite which row to add the new column value to.
Typically, you would do it with a SQL statement like

```
UPDATE Table SET column = ? WHERE column2 = ?
```

where `column2` is some other column in the table.

So something like this is slow but possible:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT column2 FROM Table ORDER BY column2')
column2 = [row[0] for row in cursor]
for j, c in zip(lst, column2):
    cursor.execute('UPDATE Table SET column = ? WHERE column2 = ?', [j, c])
```

A better solution (if possible) is to hold off `INSERT`ing into the table until you've assembled all the information needed and then doing a single `INSERT`.

---

PS. If you re-arrange your program to collect all the data to be inserted into a list of rows, `args`, then you can call

```
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO ...', args)
```

which will be faster than many calls to `cursor.execute`.

Comment: i see.  thanks for the clarification.  i guess i didn't realize that adding all the info at once would be that much better.  i will try to rearrange the code to do that.

Answer (score 0):

A full example using `INSERT INTO` courtesy of [Python Central](http://pythoncentral.io/advanced-sqlite-usage-in-python/):

> ```
> # Import the SQLite3 module
> import sqlite3
> db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
> c = db.cursor()
> c.execute('''CREATE TABLE users(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, phone TEXT)''')
> users = [
>     ('John', '5557241'), 
>     ('Adam', '5547874'), 
>     ('Jack', '5484522'), 
>     ('Monthy',' 6656565')
> ]
>
> c.executemany('''INSERT INTO users(name, phone) VALUES(?,?)''', users)
> db.commit()
>
> # Print the users
> c.execute('''SELECT * FROM users''')
> for row in c:
>     print(row)
>
> db.close()
> ```

See also [Is it possible to insert multiple rows at a time in an SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database)